# Cannot Start Activity After EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK(Outgoing call) on 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-activity

I am quite new in android environment.

This problem occur on android 4.0.3 but it is working on android 2.2. I just could start activity after outgoing call. I just want to call back my activity to foreground while making phone call. but it is working on android 2.2 but it is not working on 4.0.3.

Here is my code. This code working on both version on incoming state.
But it is not working on 4.0.3 on outgoing intent. I call this intent from BroadcastReceiver. Please note that i do not want to end phone calling activity while my activity in foreground state. I set launch mode to "singleInstance" on Mainfest.xml.

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Should Start Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent callsensorintent = new Intent();
                callsensorintent.setFlags(
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
                        |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
                        |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                       );
                callsensorintent.setClassName(context,"com.example.test.sg.SensorUdp");
                context.startActivity(callsensorintent);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The call screen on ICS has a higher priority than before, so it will show on top over everything else when it's in the foreground. Now it even has a higher priority than the notification menu/curtain.
You can use a higher window priority for your application, e.g.   `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`.

Comment: Thanks Sveinung Kval,

I solve this issue by adding TimerTask. i let the call screen go to foreground first, after one second, i call my activity to foreground. it is working now. thanks anyway.